# Define new dimension while writing laspy file

Tags: python, typeerror, laspy

How can I add data to a custom defined dimension when saving a laspy file (.las) in python?

Ok, more details: I read a standard .las file with attributes X,Y,Z,I. Then I do some calculations and want to save the result as a .las file with attributes X,Y,Z,I and the additional new dimension "my_dim". As long as I know the name of the new dimension, it's no problem to define and add data to it:

```py
header = laspy.header.Header(point_format=2)
with laspy.file.File(FILEPATH, mode="w", header=header) as f:
    f.define_new_dimension(name="my_dim", data_type=5, description="My new dimension")
    f.my_dim = ...
    ...
```

However, I want to capsulate the saving process in an own function and provide additional dimensions as parameter `extra_dims` (as list of dicts, like `[{"name": "my_dim", data_type: 5, ...}]`. Now, I am still able to define the new dimension based on the parameter, but adding data is not possible. Here is the snippet:

```py
def save(extra_dims):
    header = ...
    with laspy...:
        for dim in extra_dims:
            f.define_new_dimension(name = dim["name"], data_type = ...
        # Assign X,Y,Z,I
        ...
```

For adding data `f[dim["name"]] = ...` doesn't work (neither does `f.dim["name"]`, obviously), I only get

```
TypeError: 'File' object does not support item assignment
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this, i.e. adding data to an attribute whose name is "hidden" in a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use pyhton's built in setattr() and getattr() attributes:

```
    ...
    # Assign X,Y,Z,I
    setattr(f, dim["name"], your_data)
```